# What is the proper way to insert a variable into a file path in BASH?

Tags: bash

I am working on my first script and it has been going well aside from one thing. The script is meant to be a simple script to install a software on Ubuntu devices for work. The main problem I am running into is the path the package is downloaded to is /home/(the user)/Linux_Test (custom file I have in github). Since this is suppose to run on multiple machines I am trying to make the user part of the path a variable. Currently I have

```
# Install the Agent. 
sudo dpkg -i "/home/$USERNAME/Linux_Test/'SentinelAgent_linux_v22_1_2_7 (1).deb'"
```

and the error it is throwing is:

> dpkg: error: cannot access archive '/home//Linux_Test/'SentinelAgent_linux_v22_1_2_7 (1).deb'': No such file or directory

I have changed the variable from "USERNAME" to just "USER" but that attempts to run it as root.

Comment: It seems very unlikely that the filename actually contains single quotes.

Comment: You probably just need `sudo dpkg -i "/home/$USERNAME/Linux_Test/SentinelAgent_linux_v22_1_2_7 (1).deb"`, but it seems very unusual to be using a `(1)` file.  Presumably that is an artifact of name dedup on a redundant download.  You should clean that up.

Comment: The command you wrote looks like it should work.  Part of troubleshooting code is to simplify it.  To start the troubleshooting process, how about you replace that entire line with "echo $USERNAME" and see if that does the expected thing.

Comment: Why would you expect `sudo dpkg ...` **not** to run as root?

Comment: The username of the current user is `$USER` but wouldn't `$HOME/` be more reilable than `/home/$USER/` if you are expecting to find the file in the user's home directory?

Comment: Just get rid of the single quotes. You're already quoting the spaces with double quotes, you don't need single quotes as well. Since they're inside the double quotes, they're literal characters.